# Notation: jumps of LCRL processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $(\Omega,\mathbb {P},\mathcal{F},\mathbb{F})$ be a complete stochastic basis satisfying the usual conditions, $\{T_{i}\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ a fixed family of deterministic time points in $[0,\infty)$ and $\{U_{i}\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ a family of bounded random variables such that $U_{i}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{T_{i}}$-measurable.

Moreover, let us define the pure-jump LCRL (predictable) process
$$S_{t} = \sum_{\{\;i\;:\;T_{i}<t\;\}} U_{i}$$

I'm interested in stating the dynamics of 
$$X_{t} = S_{t} + W_{t}$$
with Brownian motion $W$.

I am not fully satisfied with the obvious choice 
$$dX_{t} = \Delta S_{t} + dW_{t}$$
with $\Delta S_{t} = \lim_{s \downarrow t} S_{s} - S_{t}$, because this makes it seem like the jumps of $S$ occur at $t$ (and not immediately thereafter).

Your suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: $\Delta S_{t^+}$ ?

Comment: Does your filtration $\mathbb{F}=(\mathscr{F}_t)$ be right-continuous?

Comment: @JGWang: Yes, that's included in "usual conditions".